# Android studio manifest.xml "no suggestions" error

Tags: android-studio

Why Android studio don't give code suggestions in Manifest.xml ? I used to ctrl+space , but it didn't work .  Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 1):

try this, I believe it will resolve your issue?

```
Settings(or Preferences in mac)->Editor->Code Completion
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer Maddy , I tried to change some setting in ->Code Completion , but it didn't work again . Completion is  working in .java class , but is not working in all .xml

Comment: It could be the preview files.

Try removing the following files

`On Windows (7/8)

Go to your User Folder

[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username] (ex. C:\Users\(USER)\)
In this folder there should be a folder called .AndroidStudioPreview

On Mac OS X

Remove these files:

~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioPreview
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview`